# What does XST in the date command output mean?

Tags: date, timezone

When executing the date command (on CentOS), it gives me something like this:

> Thu May 10 20:15:07 XST 2012

My local time zone is CEST, which was at that moment 22:15:07, so the printed time seems to be GMT.

But even with some time in Google and the man pages I was not able to see what XST means...I guess it's quite simple, so who can help?

---

Edit: When setting the timezone again, the output comes like that:

> Fri May 11 10:02:33 XDT 2012

So, the printed time is fine - I am just curious about the meaning of `XST` and `XDT` in the output.

Comment: what's in your /etc/timezone?

Comment: @MarcelG: Well, there is not /etc/timezone on the machine, should there be one? In the GUI I have the situation, that it shows the GMT time in the right upper corner, but when I click on it, it'll tell me that my timezone is CEST.

Comment: I have to admit I've never used CentOS on Ubuntu this is were the timezone information is kept but after a quick search I found that CentOS uses /etc/localtime and /etc/sysconfig/clock (see for example http://kezhong.wordpress.com/2010/03/08/change-timezone-on-centos-5-4/).

Setting the timezone again might help.

Comment: @MarcelG: Ok. I did set it again, now it changed to XDT (see question).

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall the `tzdata` package which contains timezone information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ST` means "Standard Time", and `DT` "Daylight Saving Time". The X in front should be the first letter of your actual time zone - maybe X means that it is unknown.

Comment: It seems like you said that X is either unknown or a special time zone defined on the given machine (which I was not aware of).